# how to prove B1 as a consistent estimator in panel data

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, least-squares, panel-data

$Yi=a+ B_1*X_i+ B_2*Z_i+\epsilon_i$, and suppose that $Zi$ is unobservable and not correlated with $X_i$. Is the OLS estimator of $B_1$ consistent by regressing $Y_i$ on a constant a and $X_i$?

I have no idea how to prove it.